# Every time opening storyboard in Xcode, it get re-scanning all the classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Every time I open iOS storyboard of my project in Xcode, it starts to scan all the files of the project (around ~900 with all the subproject) which takes time and very annoying. Do you think it's a bug or rather Xcode configuration?
Xcode 5.0, MacOS 10.8.5

Comment: I think it's a bug. The performance of IB stopped me from using storyboards.

Comment: Although it may be a bug, you should consider having many storyboard files and not just one, you can have one for each big flow of your app.

Comment: @Coche well, this particular storyboard (one out of several from the app) contains about 10 views. should I consider this as a big one?

Comment: Actually, i have no such problem with same project in Xcode 5.0.2. =) So probably this issue can be fixed somehow.
#1 Do you encounter this issue with every storyboard, or just some of them? 
#2 Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681683/xcode-project-broken-freezes-while-scanning-classes